How can I add more than 450 custom markers to a Google map without affecting the performance of the application?
How can I add more than 450 custom markers to a Google map without affecting the performance of the application?
The markers will have operations such as adding a border behind them and then placing the logo.
I tried using isolate but the app became slow.

late GoogleMapController _controller;
late ClusterManager _manager;
final List<LatLng> _locations = List.generate(
 450,
 (index) => LatLng(
   37.7749 + index * 0.001,
   -122.4194 + index * 0.001,
  ),
);

 @override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();
 _manager = _initClusterManager();
}

 ClusterManager _initClusterManager() {
return ClusterManager<ClusterItem>(
  _locations.map((latLng) => ClusterItem(latLng)).toList(),
  _updateMarkers,
  markerBuilder: _markerBuilder,
  );
}

Future<Marker> Function(Cluster<ClusterItem>) get _markerBuilder =>
  (cluster) async {
    return Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId(cluster.getId()),
      position: cluster.location,
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
        BitmapDescriptor.hueRed,
      ),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'Cluster of ${cluster.count}'),
    );
  };

 void _updateMarkers(Set<Marker> markers) {
 setState(() {
   _controller.setMarkers(markers);
  });
 }

body: GoogleMap(
initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
target: LatLng(37.7749, -122.4194),
zoom: 10,
),
onMapCreated: (controller) {
_controller = controller;
_manager.setMapId(controller.mapId);
},
markers: _manager.markers,
onCameraMove: _manager.onCameraMove,
onCameraIdle: _manager.updateMap,
),
);
